# Is there any way to set systemUI background changed by the activity in android?

Tags: android, background

How to set attribute in my app, to change the system UI background when open my app; like the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Place this is your values-v21/styles.xml, only for Android 5.0 and up :

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and in your colors.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<item name="color_primary" type="color">#yourColor</item>
<item name="color_secondary" type="color">#yourColor</item>
<item name="color_accent" type="color">#yourColor</item>

</resources>
```